# Getting value of a promise to Promise.map?

Tags: node.js, typescript

So I am working on a project. I have data that I am saving to a database via Mongoose - one of the fields is a 'thumbnail' field. Essentially after a file is uploaded to the server then this function 'addChildren' is called and saves data about the file to the database.

I am reading files (images, text, etc.) with fs.readFile, and then using node-canvas to convert the file to base64.

HERE is my problem; all of this works when I use fs.readFileSync; but that isn't what I want. I need some guidance, perhaps, on how to properly retrieve the value and store it in 'thumbnail', BEFORE it saves to the database.

```
addChildren(files, owner) {
   return Promise.map(files, file => new module.exports({
    _id: file.contentType === FOLDER_TYPE ? new Types.ObjectId() : file.key.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0],
    ancestors: [],
    name: file.originalname,
    size: file.size,
    type: file.contentType,
    thumbnail: this.getThumbnail(file.key, file.contentType),
    owner: file.contentType === FOLDER_TYPE ? undefined : owner,
    permissions: null,
    designroom: this.designroom
  }).save());  
}
// Note: Key is essentially the unique file-path.
getThumbnail(key, type) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var canvas = new Canvas(300, 200);
    var Image = Canvas.Image;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
    var fileURL = "[url to file goes here]"    + key +"/[filename]";

    switch (type) {
      case 'image/jpeg':
        fs.readFile(fileURL, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            reject (err);
          } else {
            var img = new Image;
            img.src = data;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width / canvas.width, img.height / canvas.height);
            var result = canvas.toDataURL();
            console.log(result);
            resolve(result)
           }
        });
      break;
    }
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snippet doesn't work because `getThumbnail` returns a promise, so you can't access synchronously its resul while creating the object.

You need to create the object *after* `getThumbnail` is resolved:

```
return Promise.map(files, file => (
    this.getThumbnail(/* ... */).then(thumbnail => (
        new module.exports({
            thumbnail,
            // other fields...
        }).save()
    )
));
```